# Meaning of “It was a line”

Tags: meaning, idioms

The title sentence is a dialogue from "Friends" (the sitcom):

Monica has become acquainted with a man named Paul. On a date Paul says to Monica: "Since my girlfriend left me I haven't had sex with any girls for two years" (of course he was lying for attracting Monica's pity) and Monica believes him and pities him. And then one night she invites him to her home and ... Then when Monica finds that he is a liar, she tells the story to her friends. Joey (Monica's friend) says laughingly: "Of course, it was a line".

In the "a line", is "a" an article or something else? And what meaning does "it was a line" have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume Joey meant that this was a *pick-up line*: something you say to someone to attract them - something that is not necessarily true or meaningful in any way. IOW, it is **bait**.

To *pick* someone *up* is to get them to go out with you, have sex with you, etc.  In British English the more common expression is probably *chat* someone *up*.

Comment: There's also the more general idiom of "feeding someone a line", meaning to tell them a false or biased story in order to persuade someone to do what you want them to. I've always assumed it was derived from a fishing reference (as was "they swallowed my story hook, line, and sinker") but I have no evidence to support that.

Comment: @keshlam: Good point - consider posting it as an answer. I'm not sure *evidence to support that* is very important here - the question is not about etymology. It is only about what the term *line* means in this context. Conjecture about origin can help in such a context, by suggesting possible connotations.

Comment: After some of the comments my answers have drawn here, I'm a bit gun-shy. Comments don't get criticized as strongly.

Comment: @keshlam: Take such comments into account case by case; or ignore them, if they don't help. Ideally, they should help you improve answers, but not inhibit you from trying to help by providing answers. IOW, read the comments, but try not to feel intimidated by them. Think of readers in general, and whether you think that what you have to offer might help someone. Forget the rest.

Comment: 'I'm not sure evidence to support that is very important here' seems to fly in the face of what this site is all about. It would make more sense to me to claim that it's a line as in line of a play, line in a book ... but without supporting evidence, I wouldn't put that in an 'answer'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: By "here" I (explicitly) referred to this question (not to this site in general), which asks about the meaning and not the origin of the term. Of course, etymology info is always **welcome**, even for a question about meaning. But it is not a **requirement** for posting an answer about the meaning. That was my point.

Comment: @Drew: Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a consensus. But that's a topic for Meta and/or for some clear admin statement.  Meanwhile, if someone wants to requote that as an Answer for the sake of archival persistence,  feel free.

Comment: I'll quote Matt Gutting: 'Hi! What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references ([eg] an encyclopedia, dictionary, or some other such document). Edit your question and put in your support; then we'll be able to vote up your answer!' There are all too many websites that accept folk etymologies and give them unwarranted endorsement. That's why I rarely go to any of them ('Wordwizard' is a pleasant exception).

Comment: @keshlam I assumed that feeding someone a line derived from acting (possibly related to the work of a prompter) or to comedy where someone the comedian is fed a line that sets up a terrific comedic response.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: Actually, that's a second legitimate usage of the phrase that I'd forgotten to mention. Thanks!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That's a fine quote, but where does it say that a question about the (current) meaning of a term **requires** information about its etymology?

Comment: @keshlam: What nonconsensus are you hinting at, and what support do you have for it?

Comment: Oh, I see. By 'Good point – consider posting it as an answer. I'm not _sure evidence to support that_ is very important here – the question is not about etymology.' you meant  Good point re "feeding someone a line" – consider posting it as an answer. // I'm not sure evidence to support your suggested etymology is very important in this case – the question is not about etymology. >> I'd agree with this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: The limited formatting options and space available with 'comments' is sent to try us.

Answer (score 6):

The term *line* is often used to describe a statement that is insincere or less than true. One of the many [*[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/line)*] definitions for the term is

> informal A false or exaggerated account or story:
>   *he feeds me a line about this operation*

Similarly, [*[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/line)*] defines it as

> (slang) something said for effect, esp to solicit for money, sex, etc.: *he gave me his usual line*

And [*[Macmillan](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199777/meaning-of-it-was-a-line)*]

> [SINGULAR] a remark, excuse, or explanation that is not sincere or true
>   *Don't give me that old line.*

As @Drew notes in his answer, the term is often part of the phrase *pick-up line* and is used as an introduction to a romantic play.

While I have no authority for this observation, the term may have gotten this meaning from association with its use to describe a *line* that an actor speaks -- a statement that is not the honest thought of the speaker, but said for effect.

To answer your first question, yes, the *a* is an indefinite article.

Comment: I agree OP's *specific* context has strong allusions to ***pick-up line***. Note that's [primarily the AmE version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pick-up+line%2Cchat-up+line&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpick%20-%20up%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchat%20-%20up%20line%3B%2Cc0). Compare [BrE ***chat-up line***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pick-up+line%2Cchat-up+line&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpick%20-%20up%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchat%20-%20up%20line%3B%2Cc0)